# Any *real* problems with putting everything in header file?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, embedded, avr

I'm developing for embedded (AVR), and my projects look sth like this:

```
lib/
  - foobar.h
  - utils.h
main.c
Makefile
```

Compiling it is easy, essentially `ave-gcc main.c` with some extra flags.

However, if I want to add something bigger and split the file to h and c:

```
lib/
  - big_file.h // prototypes
  - big_file.c // implementation
  - foobar.h
  - utils.h
main.c
Makefile
```

Then I have to include this `.c` file in the `gcc` command.

I've discovered that if I just *put everything in the header*, this problem is gone. I don't really want to edit my Makefile each time I do something like this.

Is there any **real problem** this will lead to?

I don't care about "best practices", if it means easier use.

Comment: If you try to include that uber-header from more than one location, you'll get linker errors.  That sounds like a real problem.

Comment: Even with #pragma once or include guards?

Comment: By "location", I mean "translation unit".  So if you include it from "main.c" and "some_other.c", you'll hit problems.

Comment: Ah ok. So of I'll always have only main.c, I should be fine?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: That problem doesn't arise if there's only one `.c` file. But of course, you do lose the ability to compile parts of the program independently. That may not be an issue for the OP... even if it does turn their code into an ugly pile of dog droppings. :)

Comment: You'll also bring in all "private" symbols into `main.c`'s namespace.  So you might end up with nasty clashing declarations (or even worse, situations where you end up accessing/modifying the wrong data without knowing about it).

Comment: Define "everything"; do you mean function definitions as well as declarations?  That's going to lead to maintenance headaches down the line.  You said that you didn't want to edit your makefile every time you make a change; this is why you use a makefile in the first place, and depending on how you structure it, such changes should be minimal.

Comment: You are recompiling *everything* on each compilation. This will slow down the workflow on any larger project. This applies in embedded world too, I had one project that suffered from such problems.

Comment: Everything = basically header + c file together. Declarations, implementations, variables. Ofc all private is prefixed. It's worked ok so far

Comment: I'm not sure what you want us to tell you then ;)  Yes, if you're *very* careful/rigorous *and* you only have one consumer *and* you don't care about potential increases in compilation times, then this works.  (Which is obvious really, you're essentially just copy-pasting all of your "library" code into your consumer .c file.)

Comment: I really just wanted to learn about the pitfalls, so I can avoid them. It's been very informative, so mission accomplished :)

Comment: After all, you can also put everything into one single source file, so there is no "real" reason not to do it the way you want. You just have to be careful... If your reason is just to avoid any change in a Makefile, this is a (very) bad reason! For each added file you just have to modify the makefile once (overhead is very low!). And there exists tools to help you in such a task : makedepend (for example). There is also makefile's variables and defaults easy to set to do most of the task for you!

Comment: @MightyPork: I hope you didn't take my earlier comment as a personal insult - I was just trying to let you know how other C programmers would feel about the code if they had to read or work on a program that was structured like that. :) FWIW, you can do `#include "somefile.c"`. It's not recommended, but at least that way people reading your code will know that you're including executable code and not just the usual stuff one expects in a header file.

Answer (score 2):

Some problems I can think of:

1. You will be un-necessarily exposing lot of data - this could later cause an error when that declaration is different in the file where this header file gets included
2. Header files should only act as an interface so that tomorrow you can change the implementation and continue to use the same file for header.

This Programmers link has lot of discussions which I think will help you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/what-should-and-what-shouldnt-be-in-a-header-file.

Answer (score 2):

A few that spring to mind.

- You will loose the benefits of translation unit scope - everything not in a function will be global.
- Order of inclusion will be critical, circular dependencies will be difficult to resolve.
- You cannot benefit from incremental builds - everything is built every time.
- Your colleagues will hate you, and think you an idiot.

The practice may work for very small projects and trivial examples but it does not scale well to large projects or projects developed by a team.  The problems become apparent for larger and more complex projects.

> I don't care about "best practices", if it means easier use.

You should care; *best practices* have become so, exactly because they solve or prevent *real* problems.

If you want "easier to use", then this is far from the best or simplest solution. A better solution is to use an IDE with a project manager.  This will have the additional benefit of generating comprehensive and accurate dependencies, which is difficult to maintain in a manually generated makefile, so you are better off with an IDE or at least a makefile generator in any case.

Answer (score 1):

1. all your data and code is visible to everyone who includes the file.
2. portability of application reduces because, header has lot of control flow code [if any platform specific code is there], then all files where it is used may get affected. More testing and validation needed later on.
3. headers general practice is to avoid adding control there but just keen interfaces and defines.